# python dask DataFrame, support for (trivially parallelizable) row apply?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask

I recently found [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html) module that aims to be an easy-to-use python parallel processing module. Big selling point for me is that it works with pandas.

After reading a bit on its manual page, I can't find a way to do this trivially parallelizable task:

```
ts.apply(func) # for pandas series
df.apply(func, axis = 1) # for pandas DF row apply
```

At the moment, to achieve this in dask, AFAIK,

```
ddf.assign(A=lambda df: df.apply(func, axis=1)).compute() # dask DataFrame
```

which is ugly syntax and is actually slower than outright

```
df.apply(func, axis = 1) # for pandas DF row apply
```

Any suggestion?

Edit: Thanks @MRocklin for the map function. It seems to be slower than plain pandas apply. Is this related to pandas GIL releasing issue or am I doing it wrong?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
s = pd.Series([10000]*120)
ds = dd.from_pandas(s, npartitions = 3)

def slow_func(k):
    A = np.random.normal(size = k) # k = 10000
    s = 0
    for a in A:
        if a > 0:
            s += 1
        else:
            s -= 1
    return s

s.apply(slow_func) # 0.43 sec
ds.map(slow_func).compute() # 2.04 sec
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `dask` module. For mulit-processing, python module `multiprocessing` works well for me when I have to process a big dataframe row-by-row. The idea is also very simple: use `np.array_split` to split big dataframe into 8 pieces and process them simultaneously using `multiprocessing`; Once it's done, use `pd.concat` to  concat them back to the original length. For a related post with full code example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904354/pandas-optimizing-my-code-groupby-apply

Comment: Thanks, very nice. The problem of multiprocessing module is that you need to have a named function (not lambda) and put it out of name=="main" block. That makes research codes badly structured.

Comment: If you just want to use a better multiprocessing you could look at [multiprocess](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess) by @mike-mckerns .  You could also try out dask core rather than dask.dataframe and just build dictionaries or use something like https://github.com/ContinuumIO/dask/pull/408

Answer (score 74, accepted):

#### `map_partitions`

You can apply your function to all of the partitions of your dataframe with the `map_partitions` function.

```
df.map_partitions(func, columns=...)
```

Note that func will be given only part of the dataset at a time, not the entire dataset like with `pandas apply` (which presumably you wouldn't want if you want to do parallelism.)

#### `map` / `apply`

You can map a function row-wise across a series with `map`

```
df.mycolumn.map(func)
```

You can map a function row-wise across a dataframe with `apply`

```
df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

#### Threads vs Processes

As of version 0.6.0 `dask.dataframes` parallelizes with threads. Custom Python functions will not receive much benefit from thread-based parallelism.  You could try processes instead

```
df = dd.read_csv(...)

df.map_partitions(func, columns=...).compute(scheduler='processes')
```

#### But avoid `apply`

However, you should really avoid `apply` with custom Python functions, both in Pandas and in Dask.  This is often a source of poor performance.  It could be that if you find a way to do your operation in a vectorized manner then it could be that your Pandas code will be 100x faster and you won't need dask.dataframe at all.

#### Consider `numba`

For your particular problem you might consider [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/).  This significantly improves your performance.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: s = pd.Series([10000]*120)

In [4]: %paste
def slow_func(k):
    A = np.random.normal(size = k) # k = 10000
    s = 0
    for a in A:
        if a > 0:
            s += 1
        else:
            s -= 1
    return s
## -- End pasted text --

In [5]: %time _ = s.apply(slow_func)
CPU times: user 345 ms, sys: 3.28 ms, total: 348 ms
Wall time: 347 ms

In [6]: import numba
In [7]: fast_func = numba.jit(slow_func)

In [8]: %time _ = s.apply(fast_func)  # First time incurs compilation overhead
CPU times: user 179 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 179 ms
Wall time: 175 ms

In [9]: %time _ = s.apply(fast_func)  # Subsequent times are all gain
CPU times: user 68.8 ms, sys: 27 µs, total: 68.8 ms
Wall time: 68.7 ms
```

Disclaimer, I work for the company that makes both `numba` and `dask` and employs many of the `pandas` developers.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the map method and it seems to be slower than pandas apply. Could you comment on the edit of original post please?

Comment: I already use numba a lot! Thanks for the work. What I normally do is that each row of DataFrame specifies a configuration of a simulation (parameters for a complex/slow func). I do multiprocessing already, just keep an eye on better ways of doing this

Comment: @MRocklin Slightly off topic regarding pandas; i try to use map over apply because I've heard it's faster, but I'm not sure why it's faster.  Any clarification or links to clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BobHaffner no clue.  Suggest doing a small experiment and posting a "why is this the case" style stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

As of v `dask.dataframe`.apply delegates responsibility to `map_partitions`:

```
@insert_meta_param_description(pad=12)
def apply(self, func, convert_dtype=True, meta=no_default, args=(), **kwds):
    """ Parallel version of pandas.Series.apply
    ...
    """
    if meta is no_default:
        msg = ("`meta` is not specified, inferred from partial data. "
               "Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.\n"
               "  Before: .apply(func)\n"
               "  After:  .apply(func, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}) for dataframe result\n"
               "  or:     .apply(func, meta=('x', 'f8'))            for series result")
        warnings.warn(msg)

        meta = _emulate(M.apply, self._meta_nonempty, func,
                        convert_dtype=convert_dtype,
                        args=args, **kwds)

    return map_partitions(M.apply, self, func,
                          convert_dtype, args, meta=meta, **kwds)
```