# load and operate on matrices bigger than RAM - python - numpy - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ram

my tasks:

1. load from the database matrices whose dimension is bigger than my
   RAM by using (`pandas.read_sql(...)` - database is `postresql`)
2. operate on the `numpy` representation of such matrices (bigger than my RAM) using `numpy`

the problem: I get `a memory error` when even loading the data from the database.

my temporary quick and dirty solution: loop over chunks of the aforementioned data (so importing parts of the data at a time) thus allowing RAM to handle the workload. The issue at play here is speed related. time is significantly higher and before delving into `Cython` optimization and the like, I wanted to know whether there were some solutions (either in the forms of data structures like using the library `shelving` or the `HDF5 format`) to solve the issue

Comment: Would you like to explore [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)? A Dask DataFrame is a large parallel dataframe composed of many smaller Pandas dataframes, split along the index. These pandas dataframes may live on disk for larger-than-memory. This could work for you.

Comment: i am open to explore anything that works. by the way super quick answer :)

Comment: indeed. I am going through the docs and tutorials now. I see the library is though a much smaller version than pandas (understandably since it's huge). but I also see that with some tricks (https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/943) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361721/python-dask-dataframe-support-for-trivially-parallelizable-row-apply) I might be able to get the job done. I'll still need to understand how to best wrap all of this but this definetely looks promising. thank you