# simple dask map_partitions example

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I read the following SO [thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361721/python-dask-dataframe-support-for-trivially-parallelizable-row-apply) and now am trying to understand it. Here is my example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask.multiprocessing import get
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':random.sample(range(10000), 10000), 'col_2': random.sample(range(10000), 10000) })

def test_f(col_1, col_2):
    return col_1*col_2

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)

ddf['result'] = ddf.map_partitions(test_f, columns=['col_1', 'col_2']).compute(get=get)
```

It generates the following error below. What am I doing wrong? Also I am not clear how to pass additional parameters to function in `map_partitions`?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\utils.py in raise_on_meta_error(funcname)
    136     try:
--> 137         yield
    138     except Exception as e:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in _emulate(func, *args, **kwargs)
   3130     with raise_on_meta_error(funcname(func)):
-> 3131         return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
   3132 

TypeError: test_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-913789c7326c> in <module>()
----> 1 ddf['result'] = ddf.map_partitions(test_f, columns=['col_1', 'col_2']).compute(get=get)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in map_partitions(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    469         >>> ddf.map_partitions(func).clear_divisions()  # doctest: +SKIP
    470         """
--> 471         return map_partitions(func, self, *args, **kwargs)
    472 
    473     @insert_meta_param_description(pad=12)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in map_partitions(func, *args, **kwargs)
   3163 
   3164     if meta is no_default:
-> 3165         meta = _emulate(func, *args, **kwargs)
   3166 
   3167     if all(isinstance(arg, Scalar) for arg in args):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in _emulate(func, *args, **kwargs)
   3129     """
   3130     with raise_on_meta_error(funcname(func)):
-> 3131         return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
   3132 
   3133 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     75                 value = type()
     76             try:
---> 77                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
     78             except StopIteration as exc:
     79                 # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\utils.py in raise_on_meta_error(funcname)
    148                ).format(" in `{0}`".format(funcname) if funcname else "",
    149                         repr(e), tb)
--> 150         raise ValueError(msg)
    151 
    152 

ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `test_f`.

Original error is below:
------------------------
TypeError("test_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'",)

Traceback:
---------
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\utils.py", line 137, in raise_on_meta_error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 3131, in _emulate
    return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an example in [`map_partitions` docs](http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions) to achieve exactly what are trying to do:

```
ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.assign(z=df.x * df.y))
```

When you call `map_partitions` (just like when you call `.apply()` on `pandas.DataFrame`), the function that you try to `map` (or `apply`) will be given dataframe as a first argument.

In case of `dask.dataframe.map_partitions` this first argument will be **a partition** and in case of `pandas.DataFrame.apply` - a whole dataframe.

Which means that your function has to accept dataframe(partition) as a first argument and and in your case could look like this:

```
def test_f(df, col_1, col_2):
    return df.assign(result=df[col_1] * df[col_2])
```

Note that assignment of a new column in this case happens (i.e. gets scheduled to happen) BEFORE you call `.compute()`.

In your example you assign column AFTER you call `.compute()`, which kind of defeats the purpose of using dask. I.e. after you call `.compute()` the results of that operation are loaded into memory **if there is enough space** for those results (if not you just get `MemoryError`).

So for you example to work you could:

1) Use function (with column names as arguments):

```
def test_f(df, col_1, col_2):
    return df.assign(result=df[col_1] * df[col_2])


ddf_out = ddf.map_partitions(test_f, 'col_1', 'col_2')

# Here is good place to do something with BIG ddf_out dataframe before calling .compute()

result = ddf_out.compute(get=get)  # Will load the whole dataframe into memory
```

2) Use `lambda` (with column names hardcoded in the function):

```
ddf_out = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.assign(result=df.col_1 * df.col_2))

# Here is good place to do something with BIG ddf_out dataframe before calling .compute()

result = ddf_out.compute(get=get)  # Will load the whole dataframe into memory
```

---

**Update:**

To apply function on a row-by-row basis, here is a quote from the post you linked:

> **`map` / `apply`**
>
> You can map a function row-wise across a series with `map`
>
> ```
> df.mycolumn.map(func)
> ```
>
> You can map a function row-wise across a dataframe with `apply`
>
> ```
> df.apply(func, axis=1)
> ```

I.e. for the example function in your question, it might look like this:

```
def test_f(dds, col_1, col_2):
    return dds[col_1] * dds[col_2]
```

Since you will be applying it on a row-by-row basis the function's first argument will be a series (i.e. each row of a dataframe is a series).

To apply this function then you might call it like this:

```
dds_out = ddf.apply(
    test_f, 
    args=('col_1', 'col_2'), 
    axis=1, 
    meta=('result', int)
).compute(get=get)
```

This will return a series named `'result'`.

I guess you could also call `.apply` on each partition with a function but it does not look to be any more efficient then calling `.apply` on dataframe directly. But may be your tests will prove otherwise.

Comment: So if understand correctly, in order to achieve row by row operations with `dask`, I will need to create two functions: one will accept partitions and the second one will `apply` my target function to each row (of partition) in regular `pandas` sense.

Comment: Thank you for update. I am still reading and trying your update. Quick question, does `apply` from `dask` computes in parallel?

Comment: As far as I know it does.

Comment: I've got my own problems I'm trying to solve using dask and had a quick questions. The Dask documentation said to not mutate the input, but you're mutating df by assigning columns to it. Is this just a misunderstanding on my part?

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#don-t-mutate-inputs

Comment: Your understanding is correct - the example shown above does mutate the input. This should be avoided where possible just as the docs recommend.

Answer (score 6):

Your `test_f` takes two arguments: `col_1` and `col_2`. You pass a single argument, `ddf`.

Try something like

```
In [5]: dd.map_partitions(test_f, ddf['col_1'], ddf['col_2'])
Out[5]:
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=8
0       int64
1250      ...
        ...
8750      ...
9999      ...
dtype: int64
Dask Name: test_f, 32 tasks
```

Comment: I just tried it, it does not work.  `ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `test_f`.`

Comment: You can resolve `ValueError: Metadata inference failed in..` by adding a `meta='dtype'` argument to the above statement. Where dtype is your expected data type.

Comment: SummerEla Could you please add an answer that includes your suggestion?

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to run the same using meta `can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`. Any suggestions?