# How to convert convert a datetime string to timestamp in dask cudf and then sort the dataframe by this column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed, cudf

I would like to convert a datetime string to timestamp in dask cudf and then sort the dataframe by this column.

Example:

```
import dask_cudf as ddf
import pandas as pd

# Sample data (replace with your actual data)
cdf = cudf.DataFrame({
    'city': ['Dallas', 'Bogota', 'Chicago', 'Juarez'],
    'timestamp': ['2019-12-29 14:15:08 UTC', '2019-12-30 10:30:15 UTC', '2019-12-31 18:45:30 UTC', '2020-01-01 03:20:45 UTC']
})

# Create a Dask-cuDF DataFrame
dask_df = ddf.from_cudf(cdf, npartitions=2)

def to_timestamp(x):
    import time
    import datetime
    element = datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
    return datetime.datetime.timestamp(element)

dask_df['timestamp'] = dask_df['timestamp'].map_partitions(to_timestamp, meta=("timestamp", "str"))

dask_df.head()
```

I got error:

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

How can I do this for large dataframe on dask cudf ?

==========update ==========

I have tried this:

```
   dask_df["timestamp"] = dask_df["timestamp"].map_partitions(to_timestamp, meta=("timestamp", "str"))
```

and got error:

```
  TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Answer (score 0):

This [map_partitions thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125665/simple-dask-map-partitions-example) seems to cover all the tricks of using `map_partitions` on a row-by-row basis.

Furthermore, you can refactor your function somewhat. The import statements can be moved outside of the function to save on loading time. You're only using `datetime` in the function therefore you can skip on importing `time`. The function could then look like this:

```
def to_timestamp(x):
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.timestamp(element)
    return timestamp
```