# Does dask dataframe apply preserve rows order?

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, lazy-evaluation, dask

I am considering using a closure with the current state, to compute the rolling window (which in my case is of width 2), to answer my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473806/adding-a-column-to-dask-dataframe-computing-it-through-a-rolling-window),  which I have recently posed. Something on the lines of:

```
def test(init_value):

    def my_fcn(x,y):

        nonlocal init_value
        actual_value = (x + y) * init_value

        init_value = actual_value
        return init_value

    return my_fcn
```

where my_fcn is a dummy function used for testing. Therefore the function might be initialised thorugh `actual_fcn = test(0);` where we assume the initial value is zero, for example. Finally one could use the function through ddf.apply (where ddf is the actual dask dataframe).

Finally the question: this would work, if the order of the computations is preserved, otherwise everything would be scrambled. I have not tested it, since -even if it passes- I cannot be 100% sure it will always preserve the order. So, question is:

Does dask dataframe's apply method preserve rows order?

Any other ideas? Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently yes. I am using dask 1.0.0.

The following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
number_of_components = 30

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,number_of_components,size=(number_of_components, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
my_data_frame = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions = 1 )


def sumPrevious( previousState ) :

    def getValue(row):
        nonlocal previousState 
        something = row['A'] - previousState 
        previousState = row['A']
        return something
    return getValue

given_func = sumPrevious(1)
out = my_data_frame.apply(given_func, axis = 1 , meta = float).compute()
```

behaves as expected. There is a big caveat: if the previous state is provided by reference (i.e.: it is some object of some class) then the user should be careful in using equality inside the nested function to update the previous state: since it will have side effects, if the state is passed by reference.

Rigorously, this example does not prove that order is preserved under any circumstances; so I would still be interested whether I can rely on this assumption.